# Stretch a part of mesh and push the other parts away

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

For example I have this model:

[image]

I'd like to stretch the neck part. But if I simply scale it, the head is not moved so the neck will clip into it. If I use proportional editing to scale it, the head does move, but the general shape changes too.

I guess one possible way is to create an armature, set bones for the head and neck, then scale the neck bone. Is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, *Proportional Editing* can work well if you choose *Linear* mode. Select the whole head and pull:

[image]

Comment: Oh I completely misunderstood how proportional editing works lol. I tried to scale the neck instead of moving the head. Thank you very much.